# Notify that value changed in plain array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Currently I'm bound to plain array. Values of the array can be changed by external components.

Is there any possibility to send notification that value has changed and re-render DOM tree?

I can't use observables, thus `valueHasMutated` is not a solution, array is very large and contains lot of complex objects in it.

Comment: Why can't you use observables?

Comment: Because there is no schema, everything is bound dynamically in multi-tenant app.

Comment: How are you generating the HTML templates if you don't know the schema?

Comment: All the stuff described in XML document and builds on server side. Then it transforms to HTML template and binds to JSON on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the array is a member of the ViewModel (which you have control over), but you cannot change it into an `observableArray` because things outside of your control modify the array, using plain array syntax. Also, you *can* take some action after these black-box functions run, to notify the model that the array may have been mutated.

We can do this. Define an (internal) `observableArray` and define a public property on the ViewModel that wraps it. That gives you access to the `observableArray` using ordinary array syntax. However, changes to individual (non-`observable`) elements of an array do not send notifications, so you will need to provide a call to the `valueHasMutated` method of the internal `observableArray`, to be called whenever you make changes.

```
var vm = (function () {
    var arrayImpl = ['hi'];
    var obsArray = ko.observableArray(arrayImpl);
    var itemNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    var self = {
        itemNumbers: itemNumbers,
        selectedItemNumber: ko.observable(1),
        newValue: ko.observable(),
        arrayHasMutated:obsArray.valueHasMutated
    };
    Object.defineProperty(self, 'plainArray', {
        get: obsArray,
        set: obsArray
    });
    return self;
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Our app can use the `plainArray` property just like a regular array. When updates are made, call `arrayHasMutated`.

```
Item Number: <select data-bind="options:itemNumbers, value:selectedItemNumber"></select>
<br />
New Value: <input data-bind="value:newValue" />
<button data-bind="click:function () { var idx=selectedItemNumber()-1; plainArray[idx] = newValue(); arrayHasMutated(); }">Set it</button>
<ol data-bind="foreach:plainArray">
    <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
</ol>
<br />
Length: <span data-bind="text:plainArray.length"></span>
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/4jogh3k5/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you can pass another object, instead of the original array, to the consumers then you can use `defineProperty` to wrap mutations.

```
var original = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0);
var wrapper = {};
for (var idx in original) {
    (function(prop) {
        Object.defineProperty(wrapper, prop, { 
            get: function() { return original[prop]; }, 
            set: function(v) { 
                console.log("changing index " + prop + " to " + v);
                original[prop] = v;
            }
        });
    })(idx);
}
```

Obviously this only works when you change the value at an index. If your array has objects and you change one of those objects directly, like `original[0].property = "value"` then you would need to extend this technique to visit every object in the array and create an equivalent structure of wrapper objects.

Comment: When using `Object.defineProperty`, don't forget to also set `configurable: true, enumerable: true` unless you want them false, as the default values for those are `false` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Knockout.js since you tagged it.  Therefore, you can use ko.ObservableArray() and bind it to the DOM.

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var observableArray = ko.ObservableArray(originalArray);
```

See [this link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Comment: Line 2 can shorten your code sginificantly: `var watchedArray = ko.observableArray(originalArray );`and remove the whole for-in-loop. Also be aware that on IE 8 `for (index in array)` you will have to `return;`on ´index=='indexOf'` (which will be your last array index).